# Salesforce - Custom page for new related list of Custom Object

Tags: salesforce

I have custom objects A and B. The relationship between A & B is set using a custom object C, with object A & B (master detail) as fields of C.

I have created a custom lookup page to bind object B (to A) which is set as related list to Object A.

I want to invoke the custom page when  I click on New button in the related list. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this.
Here's what i did.

1. Create a button in object C to go to my new custom lookup page url
2. In Object A, I added the button in the related lists section.

So, when I load object A's data, the new button showed in the related list.

Hope this helps others looking for similar solutions.